# Nil parameter in OptionParser

Tags: ruby, optionparser

i try to set my script to run something like this

```
ruby Script.rb --ip "192.168.3.206"
```

But if there is no ip parameter then it use default "192.168.1.1

I try this code, but it's always return nil as ip

```
options = {}

OptionParser.new do |opts|
  options[:ip] = "192.168.1.1"
  opts.on("-i", "--ip", String, "Set ip") do |command_line_ip|
    options[:ip] = command_line_ip
  end
end.parse!
p options
```

Output of this code is

```
{:ip=>nil}
```

Please, tell me where is my code wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to indicate that there is an argument to your --ip switch like this:

```
opts.on("-i MANDATORY", "--ip=MANDATORY", String, "Set ip") do |command_line_ip|
```

Comment: Just to clarify. It does not have to be the string 'MANDATORY', it can be any string you'd like, it simply denotes that the command accepts a value afterwards. For example:                                                                                          ```opts.on('--width NUM', Integer, 'Set width of game board') do |w|```